# On bent combining functions

Tags: lfsr

Bent functions are Boolean functions with maximum nonlinearity and are widely studied for their potential applications in cryptography. Let's say you want to use a simple $2$-input AND gate as a nonlinear combiner for the outputs of two [linear feedback shift registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register). Because a $2$-input AND gate is a bent function, is it technically correct to call the output sequence of this combination generator a bent sequence? I need to know this for a paper I am writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  As far as I can tell, this does not appear to produce a bent sequence.  (Or, if it does, that fact requires proof/justification.)

According to Wikipedia, a "bent sequence" is a sequence of the form $(-1)^{f(x_0)}, \dots, (-1)^{f(x_{2^n-1})}$ where $x_0,\dots,x_{2^n-1}$ is the sequence of $n$-bit values in lexicographic order and $f$ is some bent function.  That's different from what you are mentioning.  If what you're mentioning happens to fit this definition, that fact is far from obvious.

I don't know if this is the same definition of "bent sequence" you are using.  If it isn't, I suggest editing your question to include the definition you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Bent functions *can* be obtained from linear feedback shift registers but not by the method that you propose. In fact, the method you propose (using an AND gate to combine the output
of two linear feedback shift registers) will *not* give you a bent function.

Bent functions (though not by that name) were studied for use as signature sequences
in direct-sequence spread-spectrum communications. In the literature on this topic,
such sequences are called *the small set of Kasami sequences*.  The sequences are
of length (or period) $2^{2m}-1$ and can be obtained as the (XOR) sum of the outputs
of two maximal-length linear feedback shift registers (LFSRs) of lengths $2m$ and $m$ respectively. The feedback polynomials of the LFSRs thus are primitive polynomials of degrees $2m$ and $m$ respectively, and they produce maximal-length LFSR sequences
($m$-sequences) of periods $2^{2m-1}$ and $2^m-1$ respectively. Thus, $2^m+1$ copies
of one period of the shorter sequence get added into one period
of the longer sequence, and the result is of
period $2^{2m}-1$. A total of $2^m-1$ distinct sequences can generated by using
a fixed nonzero initial loading of the longer LFSR and $2^m-1$ nonzero initial
loadings of the shorter LFSR.
Note that one cannot choose both feedback polynomials arbitrarily.
If the longer polynomial is chosen as a specific primitive polynomial of degree
$2m$, then only one primitive polynomial of degree $m$ will give you a small set
of Kasami sequences.  If the shorter polynomial is chosen first, then the longer
one must be chosen from a subset of the  set of all
primitive polynomial of degree $2m$.  For more details, see the paper
D. V. Sarwate and M. B. Pursley, "Cross-correlation properties of pseudorandom and
related sets of sequences," *Proc. IEEE,* May 1980.

The set of sequences thus generated are of period or length $2^{2m}-1$ whereas
the description of bent functions says they are of length $2^{2m}$.
To relate this to Wikipedia's version, consider the Boolean function
$$f(\mathbf x) = f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_2m) 
= x_1x_2 \oplus x_3x_4 \oplus \cdots \oplus x_{2m-1}x_{2m}.$$
Wikipedia'a definition says that the bent function is the sequence
of values of $(-1)^{f(\mathbf x)}$ as we cycle through the $2^{2m}$
values of $\mathbf x$ in lexicographic order. A sequence from the
small set of Kasami sequences cycles through all the *nonzero*
values of $\mathbf x$ in a *different* order, usually in what might
be called shift-register order (successive contents of a
length-$2m$ maximal-length LFSR) or Galois-field order
(polynomial representation of successive powers of a primitive
element of $\mathbb F_{2^{2m}}$.  So, if you need the
symbols in Wikipedia order, you are going to have to do
a permutation of the $2^{2m}-1$ bits from the output
of the XOR gate that adds the two seqeuences and prepend
a $+1$ to get the missing $(-1)^{f(\mathbf 0)}$.